# Параметр amount внутри метода для онлайн-оплаты необходимо задать через переменную

Tags: javascript, post, методы, liquid

```
    payment.openPopup({
    amount: 0,
    comment: 'Оплата заказа',
    locale: 'ru',
    paymentMethod: 'ONLY_SBP',
    successSbpUrl: 'https://bfkh.ru/',
});
```

Есть виджет для оплаты на сайте (взят с документации Райф.банка, если кому-то интересно). Нужно заменить amount, который обычно задается числом (тип значения тем не менее string) на переменную, т.к. в интернет-магазине невозможно заранее узнать сумму заказа.

Можно ли вызвать переменную внутри метода и как? Сумма заказа хранится в переменной item.total_price (шаблоны liquid).

Comment: По первых, если она (переменная) хранится в объекте, то это уже технически пропорция, а не переменная. Во-вторых, вызывают не переменные, а функции. Порекомендовал бы вам [ознакомится с терминами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary). И всё на самом деле элементарно, если конечно я вас правильно понял: `payment.openPopup({ amout: +item.total_price, ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
payment.openPopup({
    amount: `${item.total_price}`, 
    comment: 'Оплата заказа',
    locale: 'ru',
    paymentMethod: 'ONLY_SBP',
    successSbpUrl: 'https://bfkh.ru/',
});

payment.openPopup({
    amount: Number(`${item.total_price}`), // number
    comment: 'Оплата заказа',
    locale: 'ru',
    paymentMethod: 'ONLY_SBP',
    successSbpUrl: 'https://bfkh.ru/',
});
```

item.total_price - Тут указать правильную переменную, что бы ее было видно.